# Keystone exception during Openstack's Freezer installation

Tags: installation, plugins, openstack, devstack

I'm trying to install Openstack on a Virtual Machine for a project, but I'm having issues with the last two steps described in https://docs.openstack.org/freezer/latest/install/install-ubuntu.html#finalize-installation.
First I installed Devstack following the instructions in https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/#install-linux and now I'm trying to add the Freezer plugin. I followed the guide, but when I run the command to start the freezer scheduler I get the following error:

> stack@node1:~/freezer/freezer$ sudo freezer-scheduler --config-file scheduler.conf start
> 2021-09-09 18:10:38.213 2377889 ERROR freezer.scheduler.freezer_scheduler [-] Could not find requested endpoint in Service Catalog.: keystoneauth1.exceptions.catalog.EndpointNotFound: Could not find requested endpoint in Service Catalog.
> Could not find requested endpoint in Service Catalog.

Using `openstack endpoint list` shows these endpoints

[image: screenshot of endpoints].

I believe the exception's meaning is that no Keystone endpoint is found, but there is one in the list (which was automatically added during the devstack installation).

Answer (score 0):

sudo freezer-scheduler --config-file /etc/freezer/scheduler.conf --os-auth-url http://vip:5000/v3 --os-project-name xxxxxx --os-username xxxxxx --os-password xxxxxx --os-user-domain-name default --os-project-domain-name default  start